# CardView above Recycler view,Scroll as One

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to place a card view above a recycler view. I Would like to scroll my card view and recycler view as one. The problem is, only the recycler view is scrolling and the contents of the recycler view are quite distorted in size.
This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ0SS.png)

Here's my xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/blogListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />
```

Would Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: put your constraint layout inside a nested scrollview

Comment: you may use your cardView in a collapse view as appbar to collapse it while scrolling and show it back when it is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your `recyclerview` and `cardView` in a `scrollView`, and add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` in recycerlview

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/blogListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi bipin. It's showing me this error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: Update: I put both of them in linear layout. Works fine..Thank you

Comment: this calls onBindViewHolder for all the items of recyclerview instead of ones which are can be visible

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="50dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbarSize="1sp">
            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="50dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/proximanova_regular" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/proximanova_regular" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please add some info talking about what you've changed and why